# type conversion at method calling

Tags: java

```
public class Demo1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
                    show('A','A');
    }
    public static void show(char c, long a){
        System.out.println("long-char");
    }
    public static void show(char c, int a){
        System.out.println("char-int");
    }
}
```

Output : `char-int`

But when I change the order of parameters in the first `show()` method (replacing 
`public static void show(char c, long a){}` with `public static void show(long a, char c) {}`), I get a compilation error.

Comment: Can you put the error in the question?

Comment: Please state the error you are seeing (I guess it is ambiguous method call).

Comment: Yes, @AndyTurner it is an ambiguous method call.

Comment: error: reference to show is ambiguous.Both method show(long, char) in Demo1 and show(char, int) in Demo1 match

Comment: @AndyTurner, can u explain, how it will be ambiguous call only by changing order of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler says that it is an ambiguous method call, because it is.

The general approach taken for overload resolution is to find the most specific applicable method, given the number and types of the actual parameters.

In the first case, the two methods have `char` as their first parameter; so it is only down to choosing whether the int or long overload is more specific, given that the actual parameter is a `char`: it is the `int` overload which is more specific, because `int` is narrower than `long`.

In the second case, one method has char as the first parameter; one method has char as the second parameter. So, given that the actual parameters are both `char`s, one of the parameters has to be converted (widened) to invoke either of the methods.

The language spec does not define that one is more specific than the other in such a case; they are both considered equally applicable, so the method call is ambiguous, and thus is a compile-time error.